# Perl for Windows for Eclipse syntax checking that contains EXPECT and SWITCH?

Tags: eclipse, perl, switch-statement, expect, epic

We are running a CentOS Linux server, on which Perl 5.8.8 is installed. We cannot update Perl on this system.

I am installing Eclipse with EPIC to do some Perl coding onto my Windows 7 workstation. This requires that I install Perl on the workstation as well. I've installed a few different versions of Perl and they all have issues for us... Our code makes use of the **Switch** and **Expect** commands.

- Strawberry Perl 5.8.8.4 has Switch.pm, but not Expect.pm.
- DWIM Perl 5.14.2.1 does has Switch.pm, but can't locate it. It also doesn't have Expect.pm.
- ActivePerl 5.16.3.1604 has Switch.pm, but can't locate it. It also doesn't have Expect.pm.

Can someone recommend a Perl that I can install on my workstation that will provide these modules? Alternately, is there a way to install these modules?

Comment: How about running linux on your workstation via virtual machine?

Comment: Might be possible, but it seems like overkill to me. There should be a PERL implementation that would meet my needs.

Comment: Did you try installing the module you need from CPAN under strawberry?

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod#Can_I_use_this_module_with_ActivePerl_on_Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with strawberry perl:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Expect'
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this the install script ends complaining that it can't locate IO/Pty.pm...    Can't locate IO/Pty.pm in @INC (@INC contains: blib\lib blib\arch C:/strawberry/
perl/lib C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib .) at blib\lib/Expect.pm line 22.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at blib\lib/Expect.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 27.
dmake.EXE:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  RGIERSIG/Expect-1.21.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK

Comment: Gah!  Get a mac!  You could try cygwin.  That should let you compile stuff and add modules.

Comment: It looks like this all depends on IO:Tty, which is not supported on Windows. Looks like I might to install Cygwin for PERL support. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat answered by [`Expect - Can I use this module with ActivePerl on Windows?`](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod#Can_I_use_this_module_with_ActivePerl_on_Windows?)

> Up to now, the answer was 'No', but this has changed.
>
> You still cannot use ActivePerl, but if you use the Cygwin environment (http://sources.redhat.com), which brings its own perl, and have the latest IO::Tty (v0.05 or later) installed, it should work (feedback appreciated).

Comment: Unfortunately, EPIC in Eclipse still cannot find Expect. When I try to install it I am told of missing dependencies for Pty and Tty.  I can try to install it again if you'd like me to provide output.